# Как разбирать по этимологии слово "друг"?

Tags: этимология

Нужен этимологический разбор слова "друг".

Answer (score 2):

Этимологически происхождение слова ДРУГ объясняется по-разному. Одни полагают, что праслав. корень drugъ первонач. значил «спутник, товарищ в воен. походе». Другие считают, что праслав. *drugъ образовано с помощью суф. -g-ъ от той же основы drou-, что в словах* дерево, дрова,* и буквально значит «поддержка, надежа, опора». (По данным Этимологического словаря Г.П.Цыганенко. Сходное объяснение и в Историко-этимологическом словаре П.Я. Черных).

Comment: Ваша версия, "drugъ", кажется наиболее убедительной, учитывая наличие женского рода "дружка".

Comment: Дружка (муж. р.) = друг женихов, брачный друг, провожатый жениха: http://www.perepelka.org/_0155.htm

Answer (score -3):

Значение (семантика) слова ДРУГ, ст.-сл. ДРОУГЪ: верный, преданный - и справедливо было бы сравнение с такими словами как:

true [тру] (англ.), truu [тру] (эст.),  treu [трой] (нем.), tro, tryg [тру, трюг] (дат.), trogen [труген] (шв.), tryggr [трюггр] (др.-сканд.), triggws [триггус] (гот.) - верный, преданный.

Ведь не случайно словосочетание, и у англичан, и у нас: true friend [тру фрэнд] - верный друг. И дружина - это объединение верных, преданных друг другу боевых товарищей.

Ср. аналогичную семантическую пару:

ustav [устав] (эст.) - верный;

ystävä [юстявя] (фин.) - друг;

устав (др.-русск.) - закон (он же: правда - а в англ. -  truth [труус] ).

Comment: TRUU = USTAV(эст.) - верный, преданный, надежный. http://www.eki.ee/dict/evs/index.cgi?Q=truu&F=M&C06=ru

Comment: Римма, большое спасибо за поддержку. Online этимологический словарь эстонского очень полезный ресурс, TRUU и USTAV там можно посмотреть.

А герм. TRUE и его вариации можно видеть здесь:

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=true 
Old English triewe (West Saxon), treowe (Mercian) "faithful, trustworthy, honest, steady in adhering to promises, friends, etc.," from Proto-Germanic *treuwaz "having or characterized by good faith" (source also of Old Frisian triuwi, Dutch getrouw, Old High German gatriuwu, German treu, Old Norse tryggr, Danish tryg, Gothic triggws "faithful, trusty").

Comment: далее указано: from PIE *drew-o-, a suffixed form of the root *deru- "be firm, solid, steadfast."

т.е. тот же корень, что и у TREE, ДРЕВО, ДЕРЕВО

Tree [трии] (англ.), trä [трэ] (шв.), dāru, dru- [дару, дру-] (санскр.), dauru, -dru- [дауру, дру-] (авест.), deraxt [дерахт] (фарси), darxat [дархат] (урду), darakhat [дарахат] (панджаби), dar [дар] (курдск.) - древо, дерево; δρυς [drys, дрис] (гр.) - дуб; и т.д.

Comment: А для TREE у Simo Parpola в Etymological Dictionary of the Sumerian Language, 2016, находим привязку к:

Diri, dirig [дири, дириг] (шумерск.) - расти высоким; наполняться; разбухать, разрастаться, становиться огромным, массивным; быть способным, сильным; прил. способный, сильный, властный.

Comment: Но для ДРУГ, ст.-сл. ДРОУГЪ прямая связь именно с TRUU (эст.), TRUE (англ.), TRO, TRYG, TRUGG (дат., шв.), - верный, надежный. Пришло к нам, скорее всего, с варяжских времён.